# non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use gam function. But i am getting an error which states non numeric argument to binary operator. i tried using lapply(sample,as.numeric) but it did not work i also tried as.numeric(sample$VOl) even that did not fix my problem.

```
library(mgcv)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
model<-gam(lmpg~SP*lhp+WT*lhp+I(SP^2)+I(WT^2)+I(lhp)^2)+VOL
plot(model)
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

my sample looks like this

```
   VOL  SP   WT     lmpg      lhp
1   89  96 17.5 4.180522 3.891820
2   92  97 20.0 4.025352 4.007333
3   92  97 20.0 4.023564 4.007333
4   92 105 20.0 3.891820 4.248495
5   92  96 20.0 3.839452 3.970292
6   89 105 20.0 3.832980 4.248495
7   92  97 20.0 3.815512 4.007333
8   50  98 22.5 4.080922 4.127134
9   50  98 22.5 3.975936 4.127134
10  94 107 22.5 3.770459 4.382027
11  89 103 22.5 3.716008 4.290459
12  50 113 22.5 3.711130 4.521789
13  99 113 22.5 3.711130 4.521789
14  89 103 22.5 3.698830 4.290459
15  89 100 22.5 3.678829 4.189655
16  89 103 22.5 3.671225 4.290459
17  91 106 22.5 3.660994 4.356709
18  50 113 22.5 3.658420 4.521789
19  91 106 22.5 3.642836 4.356709
20 103 109 25.0 3.742420 4.499810
21  99 110 25.0 3.711130 4.521789
22 107 101 25.0 3.706228 4.304065
23 101 111 25.0 3.688879 4.553877
24  96 105 25.0 3.671225 4.394449
25  89 111 25.0 3.658420 4.553877
26  50 110 25.0 3.648057 4.521789
27 117 110 25.0 3.648057 4.521789
28  99 110 25.0 3.648057 4.521789
29 102 109 25.0 3.384390 4.499810
30 104  90 27.5 3.848018 3.951244
31 107 112 27.5 3.591818 4.634729
32 114 103 27.5 3.586293 4.430817
33 101 103 27.5 3.586293 4.430817
34  97 111 27.5 3.566712 4.624973
35 113 111 27.5 3.563883 4.624973
36 101 102 27.5 3.558201 4.394449
37  98 106 27.5 3.558201 4.499810
38  88 106 27.5 3.555348 4.499810
39  86 109 30.0 3.502550 4.624973
40  86 109 30.0 3.493473 4.624973
41  92 120 30.0 3.475067 4.867534
42 113 106 30.0 3.471966 4.553877
43 106 106 30.0 3.471966 4.553877
44  92 109 30.0 3.471966 4.624973
45  88 106 30.0 3.471966 4.553877
46 102 105 30.0 3.449988 4.532599
47  99 108 30.0 3.449988 4.605170
48 111 108 30.0 3.446808 4.605170
49 103 107 30.0 3.446808 4.584967
50  86 120 30.0 3.440418 4.867534
51 101 109 35.0 3.517498 4.744932
52 101 109 35.0 3.484312 4.744932
53 101 109 35.0 3.443618 4.744932
54 124 109 35.0 3.443618 4.744932
55 113 133 35.0 3.414443 5.192957
56 113 125 35.0 3.363842 5.075174
57 124 115 35.0 3.332205 4.867534
58  92 102 35.0 3.332205 4.564348
59 101 109 35.0 3.332205 4.744932
60  94 104 35.0 3.332205 4.605170
61 115 105 35.0 3.332205 4.605170
62 111 120 35.0 3.321432 4.976734
63 116 107 40.0 3.242592 4.787492
64 131 114 40.0 3.230804 4.941642
65 123 114 40.0 3.173878 4.941642
66 121 117 40.0 3.161247 5.010635
67  50 122 40.0 3.161247 5.105945
68 114 122 40.0 3.161247 5.105945
69 127 122 40.0 3.161247 5.105945
70 123 122 40.0 3.161247 5.105945
71 112 148 40.0 3.157000 5.501258
72  50 160 40.0 3.152736 5.634790
73 135 121 40.0 3.152736 5.087596
74 132 121 40.0 3.139833 5.087596
75 160 110 45.0 3.131137 4.941642
76 129 110 45.0 3.131137 4.941642
77 129 121 45.0 2.970414 5.164786
78  50 165 45.0 2.895912 5.774552
79 115 140 45.0 2.844909 5.472271
80  50 147 45.0 2.833213 5.572154
81 119 157 45.0 2.815409 5.686975
82 107 130 55.0 2.580217 5.463832
```

can any one please help me with this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're adding `VOL` to `gam(...)`. You probably want `VOL` as part of the formula inside the call to `gam(...)`, no?

Comment: Oh yeah thank you. But now when i am trying to plot model i get an error which says "Error in plot.gam(model) : 
  No terms to plot - nothing for plot.gam() to do".

Comment: Well, you have to tell `gam(...)` what data frame to use, as in `gam(formula,data)`. It doesn't look like you've done that.

Comment: I have coded it. sorry i did not update the entire gam. my gam function is used like this model<-gam(lmpg~SP*lhp+WT*lhp+I(SP^2)+I(WT^2)+I(lhp^2)+VOL,family=gaussian, data=sample). when i try to plot(model) i get the error which i mentioned

Comment: Update your question.

Comment: model<-gam(lmpg~SP*lhp+WT*lhp+I(SP^2)+I(WT^2)+I(lhp^2)+VOL,family=gaussian,data=sample)
plot(model)
when i try to run this piece of code i get an error as follows "Error in plot.gam(model) : 
  No terms to plot - nothing for plot.gam() to do".

Comment: i would really appreciate your help in solving this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please update the question with everything you've tried in the comments. It makes it far easier to follow and more likely that someone will help you.

Comment: library(mgcv)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
model<-gam(lmpg~SP*lhp+WT*lhp+I(SP^2)+I(WT^2)+I(lhp^2)+VOL,data=sample)
plot(model)
par(mfrow = c(1,1)), I am trying to run this code but i am getting an error which says "Error in plot.gam(model) : 
  No terms to plot - nothing for plot.gam() to do." thank you

Comment: You're missing the point Dean. We're telling you to *edit the question*, not add to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
library(mgcv)
model.mcgv<-gam(lmpg~SP*lhp+WT*lhp+I(SP^2)+I(WT^2)+I(lhp^2)+VOL,
                family=gaussian, data=sample)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(model.mcgv, all.terms=T)
```

I think this may be a bug in `mcvg::plot.gam`. Looking at the code, it appears that there is a parameter, `all.terms` which defaults to `FALSE`. If `FALSE`, the method sets `n.para <- 0` and exists with the error you're getting.